# In "hot" tab the question are displaying as "on hold" but they are actually "duplicate" questions

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, hot-questions, on-hold, hot-tab

In the [hot tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot), the duplicate questions are displaying with the **[on hold]**.

Actually these are supposed to be display as **[duplicate]**.

GIF for the same:

> [image: Duplicate - Onhold issue]

---

**Update:** In the [week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=week) and [month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=month) tabs also, there are few of the **[duplicate]** questions are displaying with **[closed]**.