# Remove post from the related list if it's in the linked list already

Tags: feature-request, related-questions, linked-questions

In my [recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302452/339911) I noticed that one post exists in both: linked and related lists.

> [image: linked related]

I can't find any reason to duplicate it on the single page.

Is it possible to remove question from the related list if it's in the linked list already?

Comment: To answer your question before you ask it: a bug which is marked as by design is the same as a declined feature request, i.e. this has been requested to "fix" before and the fix declined. You can appeal that, but need to edit first with good (new) reasons.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This has been "declined" over 6 years ago. I think SE now is not the same as SE those days. Moreover it was declined without any clarification from the person who put "status-bydesign" tag. So we have a right to revise that decision.

Comment: There is already answer from Pops explaining why it's by design, Jeff probably didn't have anything to add. Like I said, if you'll edit this and make it clear you appeal the rejection of the bug report, and not just re-asking it, I'll happily reopen.

Comment: There's another feature request from 2020 asking for the same thing, so I've now edited the duplicates list to list that question first: [The same question should not be under both Linked and Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357145/335251)